# How to Modify Font/Image Size and Hide Info Icon in PKPass?

Tags: laravel, pkpass

I'm working on creating PKPasses and I need to customize the font/image size and hide the info icon next to the barcode, which opens the back side of the pass. Since I don't have much information to display on the back side, I want to hide the icon.

Could someone please guide me on how to achieve these customizations in PKPasses? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've already tried adjusting the font/image size and exploring the pass configuration options, but I'm unsure how to proceed with hiding the info icon. Looking forward to helpful responses. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.